# clarification about working of two pointer approach

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have some doubts about using two pointer approach.

Case 1: - Suppose we have an array A, that is sorted and a target value B. We want to find out if there exist two elements whose difference is equal to B or not.

```
int helper(vector<int> &A, int B)
{
    int left = 0, n = A.size();
    int right = left + 1;
    while (right < n)
    {
        int currDiff = A[right] - A[left];
        if (currDiff < B)
            right++;
        else if (currDiff > B)
        {
            left++;
            if (left == right)
                right++;
        }
        else
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Case 2: - Suppose we have an array A, that is sorted and a target value B. We want to find out if there exist two elements whose sum is equal to B or not.

```
int helper(vector<int> &A, int B)
{
    int left = 0, n = A.size();
    int right = n - 1;
    while (left < right)
    {
        int currSum = A[right] + A[left];
        if (currSum < B)
            left++;
        else if (currSum > B)
        {
            right--;
        }
        else
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The doubt is that in case 1 we set both pointers on the left side(`left = 0, right = left + 1`) and start scanning while in case 2 we set one pointer on the left side and the other one on the right side(`left = 0, right = A.size() - 1`).

I am a bit confused about how this is working.

Comment: Because they use completely different comparison algorithms.

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit @SamVarshavchik. In both cases, our goal is to find a given target value.

Comment: Well, as you can see, one of these has three `if` statements inside the loop, the other one has just two; and that's not the only difference. `if` statements are not just some kind of a minor detail. `if` statemens are very important, and they make crucial decisions about what happens next. The two algorithms are very different.

Answer (score 0):

There's no rule that you must have to set the two pointers in different way. It's all about the algorithm you're following. It may be good, it may be bad. Let's say, for difference, we set the `left=0` and `right=A.size()-1`. As the given array `A` is sorted, the first difference between `A[right]` and `A[left]` will be maximum.

```
    int currDiff = A[right] - A[left];    //max possible value for currDiff for A
```

So, now if `currDiff` is greater than the given number, what will you do? increase the `left` or decrease the `right`? Let say you do the later one, I mean decrease the `right`, and the corresponding condition satisfies again, do the same, decrease the `right`. Now, let say now you got the `currDiff` is smaller than the given number, what will you do? increase the `left`? probably. But in the next iteration, if you get the same condition satisfied, that is, `currDiff` is still smaller than the given number, what will you do now? Again increase the `left`? What if increasing the `right` in this particular position would give you the result?

So, you see, there arises a lot of cases needed to be handled if you started the `finding diff of pair` having left and right in the opposite ends.

Finally, what I want to say is, it's all about the algorithm you are following, nothing else.